# simulate x percentage of missing and error in data in r

Tags: r, loops, missing-data

I would like to perform two things to my fairly large data set about `10 K x 50 K` . The following is smaller set of `200 x 10000`.

First I want to generate 5% missing values, which perhaps simple and can be done with simple trick:

```
# dummy data 
set.seed(123)
# matrix of X variable 
xmat <- matrix(sample(0:4, 2000000, replace = TRUE), ncol = 10000)
colnames(xmat) <- paste ("M", 1:10000, sep ="")
rownames(xmat) <- paste("sample", 1:200, sep = "")
```

Generate missing values at 5% random places in the data.

```
N <- 2000000*0.05 # 5% random missing values 
inds_miss <- round ( runif(N, 1, length(xmat)) )
xmat[inds_miss] <- NA
```

Now I would like to generate error (means that different value than what I have in above matrix. The above matrix have values of 0 to 4. So what I would like to do:

(1)  I would like to replace x value with another value that is not x (for example 0 can be replaced by a random sample of that is not 0 (i.e. 1 or 2 or 3 or 4), similarly 1 can be replaced by that is not 1 (i.e. 0 or 2 or 3 or 4). Indicies where random value can be replaced can be simply done with:

```
  inds_err <- round ( runif(N, 1, length(xmat)) )
```

If I randomly sample 0:4 values and replace with the indices, this will sometime replace same value with same value ( 0 with 0, 1 with 1 and so on)  without creating error.

```
errorg <- sample(0:4, length(inds_err), replace = TRUE)
xmat[inds_err] <- errorg
```

(2) So what I would like to do is introduce error in xmat with missing values, However I do not want `NA` generated in above step be replaced with a value (0 to 4). So `ind_err` should not be member of vector `inds_miss`.

**So summary rules** :

(1) The missing values should not be replaced with error values

(2) The existing value must be replaced with different value (which is definition of error here)- in random sampling this 1/5 probability of doing this.

How can it be done ? I need faster solution that can be used in my large dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    inds_err <- setdiff(round ( runif(2*N, 1, length(xmat)) ),inds_miss)[1:N]
    xmat[inds_err]<-(xmat[inds_err]+sample(4,N,replace=TRUE))%%5
```

With the first line you generate `2*N` possible error indices, than you subtract the ones belonging to `inds_miss` and then take the first N. With the second line you add to the values you want to change a random number between 1 and 4 and than take the mod 5. In this way you are sure that the new value will be different from the original and stil in the 0-4 range.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an if/else solution that could work for you.  It is a for loop so not sure if that will be okay for you.  Possibly vectorize it is some way to make it faster.

```
# vector of options
vec <- 0:4

# simple logic based solution if just don't want NA changed
for(i in 1:length(inds_err){
  if(is.na(xmat[i])){
    next
  }else{
    xmat[i] <- sample(vec[-xmat[i]], 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing ever "equals" NA. You are clearly new to R. Please test your code before posting.

Comment: @BondedDust, this was implied to be appended to his existing code. Obviously in my code, several objects don't even exist by itself. Chill out.

Comment: Your code is syntactically and semantically incorrect. It's  going to throw an error to test for equality of something to NA. Telling me to "chill out" doesn't change that.

Comment: For anyone else reading this, the `==` was change to `is.na` to make this work appropriately.